# Determine number of columns WinJS.UI.ListView with GridLayout

Tags: windows-8, winjs

My overall objective is to add a kind of header to each column of a GridLayout.  Not finding any kind of built-in support for this, I thought I might be able to add the headers as a separate element.  The problem is that I'll need to know how many columns are being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView has support for headers for each column that you have, unless by column you mean each column in each group in the ListView. Here's how you define the header template:

```
<div class="headertemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <button class="group-header win-type-x-large win-type-interactive" data-win-bind="groupKey: key"
        onclick="Application.navigator.pageControl.navigateToGroup(event.srcElement.groupKey)" role="link" tabindex="-1" type="button">
        <span class="group-title win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></span>
        <span class="group-chevron"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here's how to populate it on page ready:

```
listView.groupHeaderTemplate = element.querySelector(".headertemplate");
```